# How to pass additional arguments on the stack?

Tags: compiler-construction, 64-bit, nasm, calling-convention

Imagine i have a function with a lot or arguments, something like this:

```
int function(-6 integer arguments-,
             -8 double arguments-,
             int x,
             double y,
             int a,
             double b) {
  // skynet initiation code
}
```

According to the System V AMD64 ABI calling convention, the first 6 integer arguments should be passed in the `RDI, RSI, RDX, RCX, R8, R9` registers, and the first 8 double arguments are passed in the `XMM0, XMM1, XMM2, XMM3, XMM4, XMM5, XMM6, XMM7` registers (i believe?).

The rest of the parameters are passed on the stack (in reverse order). Now i am wondering in what **order they should be passed**? In the example above, do i pass them ordered as [b,a,y,x]? Or do i first pass **all** integer arguments, and **then** all floating point arguments? Like [a,x,b,y]?

Most sources i find only detail how to pass integer arguments and skip (or briefly mention) that floating point arguments are passed in XMM- registers. If anyone has a good reference where i can read more than would be great.

Answer (score 2):

With the AMD64 ABI, arguments passed on the stack are simply passed in reverse order, so that the first stack argument is easily located. They are not separated into different types of memory arguments. Padding is inserted where necessary to maintain stack slot alignment (8 bytes).

Note that there are a lot more different types of argument than "integer" and "floating point". Arguments can be pointers, integers or floats too large to fit in a register, entire structures (which might be recursively decomposed, if there are enough available argument registers) and other special cases.

Agner Fog maintains a comprehensive [guide to calling conventions](https://www.agner.org/optimize/); you can also find the ABI itself on [H.J. Lu's github repository](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) and other places. (Warning: These documents are not tutorials.)